# Display post category in foreach loop with category link

Tags: posts, loop, php, categories

I have the following code to show current author post lists with post thumbnail, post title, post date and post category.

```
function my_get_display_author_posts() {
global $authordata, $post;

$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID,'posts_per_page' => 6, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) ) );

$output = '<ul>';

foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {

    setup_postdata($authors_post);

    // Build a comma separated categories list
    // You can customize as needed
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $categories_string = '';
    $separator = ', ';
    if($categories) {
        foreach($categories as $category){
            $categories_string .= $category->cat_name.$separator;
        }
        $categories_string = trim($categories_string, $separator);
    }

    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $authors_post->ID ), 'related-author' );
    $output .= '<li>
    <a class="title" href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">
    <strong>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</strong>
    <img src="'.$image[0].'"> 
    </a>
    <span>'.get_the_time('m.d.y').'</span> '.$categories_string.'
    </li>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();

$output .= '</ul>';

return $output;}
```

Please follow below link to see the output

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s250/sh/ba2c1f8f-c06e-44ef-b004-c0432b7d3a5f/12febb0db08fd9a749eee779051cb007/deep/0/Fullscreen-02-05-14-3-35-pm.png

I want to show relevant post categories with category link.

Thanks!

Comment: You can replace, $categories_string .= $category->cat_name.$separator; in for loop with below, 
 $categories_string . = '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>' . $separator;
This may solve the purpose.

Comment: Any feedback on this issue? Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fighting with the post `global`s, like `$post`, and are not getting them set correctly. Create a proper [Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and use [Core template tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) where possible and the problem will go away.

```
$authors_posts = new WP_Query(
  array( 
    'author' => 7,
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) 
  ) 
);

$output = '<ul>';

while ($authors_posts->have_posts()) {
  $authors_posts->the_post();

  // Build a comma separated categories list
  // You can customize as needed
  $categories_string = get_the_category_list();

  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'related-author' );
  $output .= '<li>
    <a class="title" href="' . get_permalink() . '">
    <strong>' . get_the_title() . '</strong>
    <img src="'.$image[0].'"> 
    </a>
    <span>'.get_the_time('m.d.y').'</span> '.$categories_string.'
  </li>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();

$output .= '</ul>';
```

Also, note that your code was far more complex than it needed to be and basically recreated, in limited form, Core functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**sintax :**  `<?php get_the_category_list( $separator, $parents, $post_id ); ?>`

> Code if u want with ',' seperated:

```
<?php echo get_the_category_list( ',', '', $post->ID ); ?>
```

> Or if custom post taxonomy category get using: artist_category is
>   custom post taxonomy

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'artist_category','<li>',',</li><li>','</li>'); ?>
```